# Debugging without stepping into function calls (gdb-peda)

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb

In gdb-peda, How can I debug Assembly without stepping into function calls, for example printf? I tried to use `ni`, but it didn't work (I read in few places that it should)

Thanks,
Omer

Comment: Define "didn't work". What happened?

Comment: It did step into the printf's instructions, instead of giving me the next instruction of the main function.

Comment: `ni` works for me in regular GDB, when debugging x86-64 executables on x86-64 Linux.  Does https://github.com/longld/peda break GDB?